# pytest python graphene subscription

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphene-python

i'm  trying to build pytest to test graphene subscription using **aiohttp** (on example below to receive random int). But i have no idea how it can be done. According to official documentation there are only information how to test queries or mutation. But nothing about subscriptiontions. Also i couldn't find any examples of testing subscriptions on internet.

If anybody knows how to do it, please let me know. Thank you very much in advance.

```
   class Subscription(graphene.ObjectType):
    random_int = graphene.Field(RandomType)

    async def resolve_random_int(root, info):
        i = 0
        while True:
            yield RandomType(seconds=i, random_int=random.randint(0, 500))
            await asyncio.sleep(1.)
            i += 1


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, subscription=Subscription)
```